# actionscript 3 automating DropDownList

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, automation, flex4

I want to automate DropDownList when DropDownList id and item index are provided.
I can get DropDownList object on that object I can set selectedIndex as

```
dropDownObject.selectedIndex=index;
```

this can change DropDownList selected item to specified index item but when I dispatch "change" event on IndexChangeEvent object it is giving typeCoersion error.

> can not convert spark.events::IndexChangeEvent@138445 to spark.events.IndexChangeEvent

Comment: Your question is not really clear, could you explain more the problem and what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I am automating dropdownlist. So for that purpose I need to dispatch events manually. So far I can select list item but can not dispatch event.

Comment: Thanks for guiding. I was manually dispatching "change" event on IndexChangeEvent object after setting newIndex which was unnecessary and causing exception. As this event is dispatched after calling openDropDown and closeDropDown. Finally solved my problem. posting the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting

```
dropDownListObject.selectedIndex = providedIndex
```

after calling

```
dropDownListObject.closeDropDown(true)
```

so far I did this and solved problem

```
dropDownListObject.openDropDown();
dropDownListObject.selectedIndex = providedIndex;
dropDownListObject.closeDropDown(true);
dropDownListObject.selectedIndex = providedIndex;
```

I was missing last line, which was resulting to set selectedIndex to default one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I am assuming you want to catch the change in the selection of the drop down list.

Do not dispatch the change event, instead, you should listen for the `valueCommit` event and not the `change` event in this case. The `valueCommit` event is designed to fire when the selected index is changed both programmatically or by user interaction.

Taken right from the docs:

> **valueCommit**
>
> Dispatched when values are changed programmatically or by user
>   interaction.

So, do something like this:

```
<s:DropDownList valueCommit="changeHandler(event)" dataProvider="{yourData}" id="dropDown"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for guiding, I was manually dispatching "change" event on IndexChangeEvent which was unnecessary because this event is dispatched when we call openDropDown and closeDropDown. So finally solved my problem. I can able to automate it. Thanks again. posting answer.